# Is there any way to obtain/build a feed with the latest CC images from flickr?

Tags: feed, flickr, yahoo-pipes

It seems that Flickr does not have a feed for images licensed by Creative Commons. 
I cannot use Yahoo Pipes since www.flickr/search does not allow robots. Is it possible to use another fair (legitimate) method?

Answer (score 1):

Probably use [Page2RSS](http://page2rss.com/) to generate a RSS feed:

> Page2RSS is a service that helps you monitor web sites that do not
>   publish feeds. It will check any web page for updates and deliver them
>   to your favorite RSS reader.